# Visual Studio 2010 settings file location

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've got a small problem concerning my settings and a virtual machine.  Recently I setup a VM so that I can perform clean checkouts and builds of the code once every week or so.  However, my documents folder lives on the company network (thanks IT department!) so my settings are shared between my real machine, and my virtual machine.

Obviously this causes never ending conflicts and is super annoying.  I feel like there should be some easy way to point the VM to a different location where it can store and use its settings internally.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out, the option is actually hiding in plain sight.  Start by navigating to:

Tools > Import and Export Settings

Now when you select any of the options (import / export / reset) you have the option to specify the directory where you want settings to be stored.  I chose 'reset', made a copy of the current settings, and re-imported them when the reset operation was complete.  It is probably just easier to change the directory and hit 'export' though.

I changed this value on both of the machines to something local (to them) and now I no longer have a conflict.